# Electrical problem garage light in ceiling

Tags: electrical

I have a light in the ceiling of my garage.  I checked the wiring and it shows 120 Volts.  However, when I install a light bulb in the socket the voltage drops to 44 volts and the light bulb does not work.  It is only on this one circuit.  Everything else in the garage works ok.

Comment: It sounds like there's a faulty connection on the circuit.  Where on the circuit are you making the voltage measurement at?

Comment: I have the light fixture hanging down and am checking the voltage on the back of the light fixture terminals.  I did first check voltage across the hot and neutral wires also before I installed the light fixture and it did show 120 volts.  But when I put in the bulb the voltage dropped to 44 volts.  Thanks for any info you can give me.

Comment: Keep working your way up the circuit (i.e. towards the panel) making voltage measurements at accessible points